# react-native run-android not completing and hangs

Tags: android, react-native

When i am putting this command it starts a JS server but after that it goes up to line "2/2 projects" and it stucks at that line...

whatever i have done on terminal is given below...

any suggestion fine...

```
C:\Users\saket>cd myapp
C:\Users\saket\myapp>react-native run-android
Scanning 558 folders for symlinks in C:\Users\saket\myapp\node_modules 
(230ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat 
install
Debug)...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 in 
C:\Users\sake
t\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1".
> Configuring > 2/2 projects
```

Comment: I am facing same issue.

File /home/aksharinux/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1 in /opt/android/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1".
> Configuring > 3/3 projects

I installed all required SDK/Tools but still it is not working

Kindly help.

Comment: have you tried by doing quit the command prompt and run again or switch off and on and run again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install following packages in android studio first. Android sdk platform must be 23.0.1 which is needed.

```
1.Google APIs
2.Android SDK Platform 23
3.Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
4.Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
```

now go again and run...

```
cd ProjectName
react-native run-android
```

Comment: i have to wait more than 30 minutes to get worked.
if not worked restart your system couple of times.